# np.isnan on arrays of dtype "object"

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working with numpy arrays of different data types. I would like to know, of any particular array, which elements are NaN. Normally, this is what `np.isnan` is for.

However, `np.isnan` isn't friendly to arrays of data type `object` (or any string data type):

```
>>> str_arr = np.array(["A", "B", "C"])
>>> np.isnan(str_arr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Not implemented for this type

>>> obj_arr = np.array([1, 2, "A"], dtype=object)
>>> np.isnan(obj_arr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

What I would like to get out of these two calls is simply `np.array([False, False, False])`. I can't just put `try` and `except TypeError` around my call to `np.isnan` and assume that any array that generates a `TypeError` does not contain NaNs: after all, I'd like `np.isnan(np.array([1, np.NaN, "A"]))` to return `np.array([False, True, False])`.

My current solution is to make a new array, of type `np.float64`, loop through the elements of the original array, `try`ing to put that element in the new array (and if it fails, leave it as zero) and then calling `np.isnan` on the new array. However, this is of course rather slow. (At least, for large object arrays.)

```
def isnan(arr):
    if isinstance(arr, np.ndarray) and (arr.dtype == object):
        # Create a new array of dtype float64, fill it with the same values as the input array (where possible), and
        # then call np.isnan on the new array. This way, np.isnan is only called once. (Much faster than calling it on
        # every element in the input array.)
        new_arr = np.zeros((len(arr),), dtype=np.float64)
        for idx in xrange(len(arr)):
            try:
                new_arr[idx] = arr[idx]
            except Exception:
                pass
        return np.isnan(new_arr)
    else:
        try:
            return np.isnan(arr)
        except TypeError:
            return False
```

This particular implementation also only works for one-dimensional arrays, and I can't think of a decent way to make the `for` loop run over an arbitrary number of dimensions.

Is there a more efficient way to figure out which elements in an `object`-type array are NaN?

EDIT:
I'm running Python 2.7.10.

Note that `[x is np.nan for x in np.array([np.nan])]` returns `False`: `np.nan` is not always the same object in memory as a different `np.nan`.

I do not want the *string* `"nan"` to be considered equivalent to `np.nan`: I want `isnan(np.array(["nan"], dtype=object))` to return `np.array([False])`.

The multi-dimensionality isn't a big issue. (It's nothing that a little `ravel`-and-`reshape`ing won't fix. :p)

Any function that relies on the `is` operator to test equivalence of two NaNs isn't always going to work. (If you think they should, ask yourself what the `is` operator actually does!)

Comment: I'd try an 'unsafe' coercion copy, though I don't what the strings will endup as.  You may need to ravel or flatten.

Comment: @hpaulj Could you expand on your suggestion? I'm not following what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I ended up building for myself:

```
FLOAT_TYPES = (float, np.float64, np.float32, np.complex, np.complex64, np.complex128)

def isnan(arr):
    """Equivalent of np.isnan, except made to also be friendly towards arrays of object/string dtype."""
    
    if isinstance(arr, np.ndarray):
        if arr.dtype == object:
            # An element can only be NaN if it's a float, and is not equal to itself. (NaN != NaN, by definition.)
            # NaN is the only float that doesn't equal itself, so "(x != x) and isinstance(x, float)" tests for NaN-ity.
            # Numpy's == checks identity for object arrays, so "x != x" will always return False, so can't vectorize.
            is_nan = np.array([((x != x) and isinstance(x, FLOAT_TYPES)) for x in arr.ravel()], dtype=bool)
            return is_nan.reshape(arr.shape)
        if arr.dtype.kind in "fc":  # Only [f]loats and [c]omplex numbers can be NaN
            return np.isnan(arr)
        return np.zeros(arr.shape, dtype=bool)
    
    if isinstance(arr, FLOAT_TYPES):
        return np.isnan(arr)
   
    return False
```

Answer (score 16):

If you are willing to use the pandas library, a handy function that cover this case is [pd.isnull](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html):

> `pandas.isnull(obj)`
>
> Detect missing values (NaN in numeric arrays, None/NaN in object arrays)

Here is an example:

```
$ python
>>> import numpy   
>>> import pandas
>>> array = numpy.asarray(['a', float('nan')], dtype=object)
>>> pandas.isnull(array)
array([False,  True])
```

Answer (score 4):

You could just use a list comp to get the indexes of any nan's which may be faster in this case:

```
obj_arr = np.array([1, 2, np.nan, "A"], dtype=object)

inds = [i for i,n in enumerate(obj_arr) if str(n) == "nan"]
```

Or if you want a boolean mask:

```
mask = [True if str(n) == "nan" else False for n in obj_arr]
```

Using `is np.nan` also seems to work without needing to cast to str:

```
In [29]: obj_arr = np.array([1, 2, np.nan, "A"], dtype=object)

In [30]: [x is np.nan for x in obj_arr]
Out[30]: [False, False, True, False]
```

For flat and multidimensional arrays you could check the shape:

```
def masks(a):
    if len(a.shape) > 1:
        return [[x is np.nan for x in sub] for sub in a]
    return [x is np.nan for x in a]
```

If is np.nan can fail maybe check the type then us np.isnan

```
def masks(a):
    if len(a.shape) > 1:
        return [[isinstance(x, float) and np.isnan(x) for x in sub] for sub in arr]
    return [isinstance(x, float) and np.isnan(x)  for x in arr]
```

Interestingly `x is np.nan` seems to work fine  when the data type is *object*:

```
In [76]: arr = np.array([np.nan,np.nan,"3"],dtype=object)

In [77]: [x is np.nan  for x in arr]
Out[77]: [True, True, False]

In [78]: arr = np.array([np.nan,np.nan,"3"])

In [79]: [x is np.nan  for x in arr]
Out[79]: [False, False, False]
```

depending on the dtype different things happen:

```
In [90]: arr = np.array([np.nan,np.nan,"3"])

In [91]: arr.dtype
Out[91]: dtype('S32')

In [92]: arr
Out[92]: 
array(['nan', 'nan', '3'], 
      dtype='|S32')

In [93]: [x == "nan"  for x in arr]
Out[93]: [True, True, False]

In [94]: arr = np.array([np.nan,np.nan,"3"],dtype=object)

In [95]: arr.dtype
Out[95]: dtype('O')

In [96]: arr
Out[96]: array([nan, nan, '3'], dtype=object)

In [97]: [x == "nan"  for x in arr]
Out[97]: [False, False, False]
```

Obviously the nan's get coerced to `numpy.string_'s` when you have strings in your array so `x == "nan"` works in that case, when you pass object the type is float so  if you are always using object dtype then the behaviour should be consistent.

Comment: Wouldn't you need `str(n)=='nan'`?

Comment: @hpaulj, it is there?

Comment: The first solution isn't what I'm looking for: I don't want the indices, but a boolean array. The second solution always returns `False` to me (python 2.7.10.2): `[x is np.nan for x in np.array([1, np.nan])]` evaluates to `[False, False]`. The third solution works, and is about twice as fast as my function on my test case. Still doesn't work for arbitrarily-shaped arrays though. :(

Comment: add a sample to your question of how it fails and I will add a working example, it is probably just a matter of checking the type

Comment: Done. Also, the one solution that you suggested that works for me will actually break if I have something in my array for which `str` also evaluates to `"nan"`. E.g. the string `"nan"`. I wouldn't want `isnan(np.array(["nan"]))` to evaluate to True. (Perhaps "nan" is a perfectly valid string with a different meaning than `np.NaN`.)

Comment: @acdr try the last edit, I am going to be away from the comp for a bit so cannot time but will add a few tests when I get back on

Comment: `def isnan(arr): return np.array([np.isnan(x) if isinstance(x, float) else False for x in arr])` is still slower than my initial function. :(

Comment: Its actually more conplicated then it needs to be,  i will edit in a bit

Comment: @acdr. x is np.nan always seems to work when the dtype is object so if your arrays are always object types it should work.

Comment: @acdr,  I added a bit more to the answer, if your dtype is not always object then then even your own solution won't work as you can see that the type can be `numpy.string_` depending on what is in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Define a couple of test arrays, small and bigger

```
In [21]: x=np.array([1,23.3, np.nan, 'str'],dtype=object)
In [22]: xb=np.tile(x,300)
```

Your function:

```
In [23]: isnan(x)
Out[23]: array([False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

The straight forward list comprehension, returning an array

```
In [24]: np.array([i is np.nan for i in x])
Out[24]: array([False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

`np.frompyfunc` has similar vectorizing power to `np.vectorize`, but for some reason is under utilized (and in my experience faster)

```
In [25]: def myisnan(x):
        return x is np.nan
In [26]: visnan=np.frompyfunc(myisnan,1,1)

In [27]: visnan(x)
Out[27]: array([False, False, True, False], dtype=object)
```

Since it returns dtype object, we may want to cast its values:

```
In [28]: visnan(x).astype(bool)
Out[28]: array([False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

It can handle multidim arrays nicely:

```
In [29]: visnan(x.reshape(2,2)).astype(bool)
Out[29]: 
array([[False, False],
       [ True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Now for some timings:

```
In [30]: timeit isnan(xb)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.03 ms per loop

In [31]: timeit np.array([i is np.nan for i in xb])
1000 loops, best of 3: 393 us per loop

In [32]: timeit visnan(xb).astype(bool)
1000 loops, best of 3: 382 us per loop
```

An important point with the `i is np.nan` test - it only applies to scalars.  If the array is dtype object, then iteration produces scalars.  But for array of dtype float, we get values of `numpy.float64`.  For those the `np.isnan(i)` is the correct test.

```
In [61]: [(i is np.nan) for i in np.array([np.nan,np.nan,1.3])]
Out[61]: [False, False, False]

In [62]: [np.isnan(i) for i in np.array([np.nan,np.nan,1.3])]
Out[62]: [True, True, False]

In [63]: [(i is np.nan) for i in np.array([np.nan,np.nan,1.3], dtype=object)]
Out[63]: [True, True, False]

In [64]: [np.isnan(i) for i in np.array([np.nan,np.nan,1.3],  dtype=object)]
...
TypeError: Not implemented for this type
```

Comment: `x is np.nan` doesn't always work as you intend it to, because it checks for identity rather than equivalence, and not all `np.nan` values have to have the same identity. For example: `[y is np.nan for y in np.array([np.nan, 1, 2, np.nan+1], dtype=object)]` returns `[True, False, False, False]` even though the first *and* fourth elements are NaN. Any function that relies on the `is` operator isn't going to be fool-proof.

Comment: An example of where it doesn't work:
`>>> x=np.array([np.float32(np.nan), 'str'],dtype=object)`
`>>> np.array([i is np.nan for i in x])`

`array([False, False], dtype=bool)`

Comment: We may need a testing function that ties `np.cancast(x,float)` before `np.isnan(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `np.vectorize` and a custom function that tests for nan elementwise.
So,

```
def _isnan(x):
    if isinstance(x, type(np.nan)):
        return np.isnan(x)
    else:
        return False

my_isnan = np.vectorize(_isnan)
```

Then

```
X = np.array([[1, 2, np.nan, "A"], [np.nan, True, [], ""]], dtype=object)
my_isnan(X)
```

returns

```
 array([[False, False,  True, False],
        [ True, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Trying this on an array of 1 million elements (repeating `["STRING_1", "STRING_2", 1.0, np.NaN]`) this solution actually tajes about 2.5 times as long to compute as my original function. Though it does work for arbitrarily-shaped arrays, so that's nice.

Comment: I updated my answer with a different function that runs about twice as fast. The `try except` indeed adds too much overhead. Can you test it against your implementation again?

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this without converting to string or leaving the Numpy environment (also very important IMO) is to use the equality definition of np.nan, where

```
In[1]: x=np.nan
In[2]: x==x
Out[2]: False
```

This is true only where x==np.nan. Therefore, for a Numpy array, the element-wise check of

```
x!=x
```

returns `True` for each element where `x==np.nan`

Comment: Except it doesn't work. Numpy 1.9.2, Python 2.7.10: `x = np.nan`, `arr = np.array([x], dtype=object)`. `arr != arr` returns `array([False], dtype=bool)`. (This is because the comparison `==` first checks identity (`is`). This will change in the future, as noted by numpy raising a `FutureWarning`, but I'm not in the future. :)

Comment: Right you are! Thanks for catching that.