# Remove NaNs from numpy array that has string values and numerical values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `(M x N)` numpy array, which contains string values, numerical values and nans. I want to drop the rows which contain `NaN` values. I've tried:

```
arr[~np.isnan(arr)]
```

however i get the error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs 
could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''save''
```

Solution that I used:

```
# get column with NaNs, find row index, store in list
nan_idx = []
for v,m in enumerate(arr[:,row]):
    if np.isnan(m):
        nan_idx.append(v)

# separate columns with strings and non strings
numeric_cols = arr[:,:some_idx]
non_numeric_cols = arr[:,other_idx:]

# remove the nans
numeric_cols = numeric_cols[~np.isnan(numeric_cols).any(axis=1)]
non_numeric_cols = np.delete(non_numeric_cols, nan_idx, 0)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently checking if arbitrary object is NaN in Python / numpy / pandas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689512/efficiently-checking-if-arbitrary-object-is-nan-in-python-numpy-pandas)

Comment: It's 2d, but what's the dtype?  Object, string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get your error if I make an object dtype array:

```
In [112]: arr=np.ones((3,2),object)
In [113]: arr
Out[113]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1]], dtype=object)
In [114]: np.isnan(arr)
...
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

That `dtype` is the only one that can mix numbers, strings and `np.nan` (which is a float).  You can't do a lot of whole-array operations with this.

I can't readily test your solution because several variables are unknown.

With a more general `arr`, I don't see how you can remove a row without iterating over both rows and cols, testing whether each value is numeric, and if numeric `isnan`.  `np.isnan` is picky and can only operate on a float.

As mentioned in the 'possible duplicate' pandas `isnull` is more general.

So basically two points:

- what's a good general test that can handle strings as well as numbers
- can you get around a full iteration, assuming the array is dtype object.

[np.isnan on arrays of dtype "object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198118/np-isnan-on-arrays-of-dtype-object)
My solution here is to do a list comprehension to loop over a 1d array.

From that I can test each element of `arr` with:

```
In [125]: arr
Out[125]: 
array([['str', 1],
       [nan, 'str'],
       [1, 1]], dtype=object)
In [136]: for row in arr:
     ...:     for col in row:
     ...:         print(np.can_cast(col,float) and np.isnan(col))
False
False
True
False
False
False
```

Comment: Look at the comment I posted. The solution would be to use `pandas.isnull`

Comment: If you have `pandas` installed.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is you can use np.sum() to sum each row up. because nan + any float = nan, so that you can get which lines incluede nan value.

```
np.sum(arr,axis = 1)
rowsWithoutNaN = [ not(np.isnan(i)) for i in b]
result = np.array( [val for shouldKeep, val in zip(rowsWithoutNaN,arr) if shouldKeep])
```

Comment: This will work if the `arr.dtype` is float.  But the OP claims it contains strings as well.