# Find row with nan value and delete it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe. This dataframe contains three cells `id`, `horstid`, `date`. The cell `date` has one `NaN` value. I want the below code what works with pandas, I want it with numpy.

First I want to transform my dataframe to a numpy array. After that I want is to find all rows where the `date` is `NaN` and print it. After that I want to remove all this rows.   But how could I do this in numpy?

This is my dataframe

```py
   id  horstid        date
0   1       11  2008-09-24
1   2       22         NaN
2   3       33  2008-09-18
3   4       33  2008-10-24
```

This is my code. That works with fine, but with pandas.

```py
d = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'horstid': [11, 22, 33, 33], 'date': ['2008-09-24', np.nan, '2008-09-18', '2008-10-24']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['date'].isna()

[OUT]
0    False
1    True
2    False
3    False

df.drop(df.index[df['date'].isna() == True])

[OUT]
   id  horstid        date
0   1       11  2008-09-24
2   3       33  2008-09-18
3   4       33  2008-10-24
```

What I want is the above code without pandas but with numpy.

```py
npArray = df.to_numpy()
date = npArray [:,2].astype(np.datetime64) 
[OUT]
ValueError: Cannot create a NumPy datetime other than NaT with generic units
```

Comment: Why don't you convert to `numpy` after you dropped the rows in `pandas`?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny because I don't want to use `pandas`. I want 
to continue my education on `numpy`. I hope this is a good reason.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But I got `ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Comment: Best answer: [convert to pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198118/np-isnan-on-arrays-of-dtype-object) or use a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution based on Numpy and pure python:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(horstid = [11, 22, 33, 33], id=[1,2,3,4], data=['2008-09-24', np.nan, '2008-09-18', '2008-10-24']))

a = df.values

index = list(map(lambda x: type(x) != type(1.),a[:, 2]))

print(a[index,:])

[[11 1 '2008-09-24']
 [33 3 '2008-09-18']
 [33 4 '2008-10-24']]
```